# Clang complains: "pointer is initialized by a temporary array"

Tags: c++, clang, allocation

I have an array of (pointers to) arrays of different lengths, which I learned I could define using compound literals:

```
const uint8_t *const minutes[] = {
    (const uint8_t[]) {END},
    (const uint8_t[]) {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 END},
    (const uint8_t[]) {8, 9, END},
    (const uint8_t[]) {10, 11, 12, END},
    ...
};
```

gcc accepts this just fine, but clang says: `pointer is initialized by a temporary array, which will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression`. What does this mean? The code *seems* to be working, but then again, lots of things *seem* to work when they point to memory that's no longer allocated. Is this something I need to worry about? (Ultimately I only really need it to work with gcc.)

**Update**: Something fishy is going on. It says [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-compound-literals/184401404) that:

> Compound literals yield lvalues. This means that you can take the address of a compound literal, which is the address of the unnamed object declared by the compound literal. As long as the compound literal does not have a const-qualified type, you can use the pointer to modify it.
>
> ```
>    `struct POINT *p;
>    p = &(struct POINT) {1, 1};
> ```

This example code seems to be doing exactly what I'm trying to do: a pointer to something defined by a compound literal. So is the clang error message legitimate? Will this end up pointing to unallocated memory when compiled with either clang or gcc?

**Update 2**:
Found some [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html): "In C, a compound literal designates an unnamed object with static or automatic storage duration. *In C++, a compound literal designates a temporary object, which only lives until the end of its full-expression.*" So it seems that clang is right to warn about this, and gcc probably ought to as well, but doesn't, even with `-Wall -Wextra`.

I can't guess why a useful C feature was removed from C++, and no elegant alternative way of accomplishing the same thing was provided.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-W` flag when using gcc ? It might show up if you are not

Comment: Yep. -Wall -Wextra, which is apparently the same thing.

Comment: have you tried removing the unnecessary `(const uint8_t[])` at the beginning of each row?

Comment: @RichardHodges it's not unnecessary. That's the syntax for compound literals. Without it the compiler expects something that looks like a pointer, and instead sees something in curly braces and complains: `error: braces around scalar initializer for type 'const uint8_t* const`

Comment: In C, this is legal at file scope, not legal at block scope. Can you please edit your question to show the scope .  In C++ compound literals are not allowed at all .

Comment: "I can't guess why a useful C feature was removed from C++, " - compound literals were added to C after C++ had already been standardized.  I'd speculate that C++ does not now add compound literals because they are not necessary: there is universal initialization in C++11, and the use of C-style arrays is discouraged because they do not have value semantics.

Comment: So this isn't valid C++, huh? Bummer... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, clang is right, and this shall be done that way:

```
namespace elements
{
    const uint8_t row1[] = {END};
    const uint8_t row2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, END};
    ...
}
const uint8_t *const minutes[] = {
    elements::row1,
    elements::row2,
    ...
};
```

You can think of more C++ solution, like using `std::tuple`:

```
#include <tuple>

constexpr auto minutes = std::make_tuple(
    std::make_tuple(), 
    std::make_tuple(1,2,3,4,5),
    std::make_tuple(8,9,10)); 

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
int main() {
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<decltype(minutes)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::get<1>(minutes))>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why I don't like your first option: it's messy. It's prone to typos, and If I re-order the rows or add a row later, there's lots of variable renaming that has to be done, or just leaving the row numbers out-of-order. Having said that, it does seem to be the most straightforward way to get the right in-memory representation of the data.

Comment: I'll have to look into your second option, with std::tuple and constexpr. I'm more comfortable with C than C++ (if you haven't guessed - but I'm using some C++ libraries for this project), and I'm coding for an embedded system with *tiny* memory, so I don't want to use any feature if I don't know exactly what's going on behind the curtain. (Yes, I realize the design philosophy behind C++, or OOP in general, is that you're not *supposed* to need to know the internal implementation, but... :)

Comment: @Josh If you  afraid of wrong ordering - you can use `BOOST_PP_ENUM` - see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/enum.html.

Comment: @Josh When talking about future insertions, deletions - you can use old trick from [basic] times - use tens numbers initially (row10,row20, ...) Then you can easily add row15 at any time...

Comment: yeah, that's exactly the "ugly" I was talking about :)  Anyway, In my case the data isn't going to change, and I don't even need the namespace because this data structure is defined in a separate file and the names of the inner parts won't have external linkage. So it's not going to be a maintenance nightmare... it's just inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

Well that means, this expression

```
(const uint8_t[]) {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 END},
```

creates a temporary object — temporary because it doesn't have any name which can last beyond the expression of which it is a part — which gets destroyed at the end of the full expression, which means this:

```
 };
```

defines *"the full expression"*, at which point all the temporary objects will get destroyed, and the array of pointers `minutes` holds pointers which point to *destroyed* objects, which is why the compiler is giving warning.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I suspected as much. So what do I *do* about it? :)

Comment: Define them as array first.  Or better redesign it. Try use `std::array`.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? There's got to be a way to do this that doesn't require creating dozens of individually-named variables that I don't actually want or intend to use... right? This compound literals method was one I got from an answer here on SO - is it actually wrong?

Comment: (This is for an embedded system, with 30k program storage and 2k ram, so I need the code to be as tiny, efficient, simple, and generally under-my-control as possible. I'm trying to avoid anything "fancy" like std::array.)

Comment: Can you define `(const uint8_t[]) {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 END}` as an array? Like `const uint8_t a0[] =  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 END};` and so on. And then use them as elements of `minutes`.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid creating dozens of variables a0, a1, a2, a3, etc. It just feels *wrong*. The other alternative is to declare the size of the outer array, and then do `minutes[0] = ...; minutes[1] = ...'`, etc. But that's almost as inelegant. Plus, it happens at runtime instead of compile time. Is there really no way to declare this fairly simple structure in a single statement?

Comment: I've updated my question to point to a source which seems to suggest my code should work. Any thoughts?

Comment: In C++ the code is illegal; in C the object either lasts until the end of the enclosing function (if there is one), or for the lifetime of the program otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

update: thanks to deniss for pointing out the flaw in the original solution.

```
static constexpr uint8_t END = 0xff;

template<uint8_t...x>
const uint8_t* make()
{
    static const uint8_t _[] = { x..., END };
    return _;
}

const uint8_t* const array[] = {
    make<>(),
    make<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>(),
    make<8, 9>(),
    make<10, 11, 12>()
};
```

Comment: This compiles, although it makes the compiled app bigger, and makes it take a bit more memory - not ideal for an embedded system. Any idea why that is? I'm also not sure what it's doing - as I understand it a static variable should allocate space once that persists between calls to the function. So how is this function allocating new space each time it's called?

Comment: It's generating one static function per different row of numbers. Each static function will contain a static array (and a hidden mutex). When you say more memory, how much are we talking? After optimisation a few hundred bytes might be worth the trade off for ease of maintenance.

Comment: Note: for the same number of parameters, this function generates only 1 array (filled with values from the first invocation).

Comment: Yup that's true. That's an oversight of mine.

Comment: @MattMcNabb hah! yay! :-) I use `_` in these functors and lambdas like this because it seems reasonably easy to me to interpret it as 'it' or 'the relevant thing'.